# Add a Load More button to an instagram feed

Tags: php, json, instagram, instagram-api

I have a working instagram feed on a website. Another developer wrote it and I need to add a Load More button so that we can see more than the 20 photos instagram loads. I'm not a programer and I read the instagram API but it just confused me more. I've tried several solutions I found on stack overflow, but keep getting parse errors. My working code is below, if anyone could show me how to add a "load more" button or even pagination I would appreciate it.

```
    <?php
       function fetchData($url){
         $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch); 
        return $result;
      }

  $client_id = "XXXXClientIDXXXX";
  $tag = $modx->getObject('modResource',22);
 $tagValue = $tag->getTVValue('photo-feed-hash');

 $url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/'.$tagValue.'/media/recent?  client_id='.$client_id;
$result = fetchData($url);


$result = json_decode($result);
foreach ($result->data as $post) {
    echo '
    <div class="photo-tile '.$post->user->username.'">
        <a class="lightbox" rel="gallery1" title="'.$post->user->username.' - '.$post->caption->text.'" href="'.$post->images->standard_resolution->url.'">
            <img src="'.$post->images->low_resolution->url.'" />
            <span>'.$post->user->username.'</span>
        </a>
    </div>';
   if (isset($_POST['more'])) {
     $result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/apple/media/recent/?access_token=964985675.5b9e1e6.aede14d1d33e4cc8b11662af423b9762&count=15&max_id=1387332905573");
$result = json_decode($result);
foreach ($result->data as $post) {
    echo '<div class="instagram-unit"><p class="instagram-desc">'.htmlentities($post->caption->text).'</p>
    <a class="instagram-link fancybox-media" rel="gallery" title="'.htmlentities($post->caption->text).'" href="'.$post->link.'">
    <img class="instagram-img" src="'.$post->images->thumbnail->url.'"/></a>
    </div>';
}
}
 ?>
  <form method="post" action="">
  <input class="submit" type="submit" name="more" />
```

Comment: You say "keep getting parse errors" - can you please *show* us the errors? How should we help you otherwise?!

Comment: The error is Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/three60/public_html/core/cache/includes/elements/modsnippet/57.include.cache.php on line 49

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 opening curly braces (`{`), but only 3 closing curly braces (`}`). That's why you get the parse error.

Change

```
if (isset($_POST['more'])) {
```

to

```
}
if (isset($_POST['more'])) {
```

and it should work.